# Where to find the source code for pandas DataFrame __add__

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to understand what (how) happens when two `pandas.DataFrame`s are added/subtracted.

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1,2], [3,4]])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([[11,12], [13,14]])

df1 + df2     # Which function is called?
```

My understanding is `__add__` function should be implemented in a class to overload `+` operator, but in the [source code](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/frame.py#L204) for `pandas.core.frame.DataFrame` and all its parent classes no such function is found.

Where should I look for the function which is doing this job?

Comment: It looks like need check [this](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/ops.py#L166).

Comment: Any update on where this went?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need check [this](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/ops/methods.py#L72):

```
def add_special_arithmetic_methods(cls, arith_method=None,
                                   comp_method=None, bool_method=None,
                                   use_numexpr=True, force=False, select=None,
                                   exclude=None, have_divmod=False):
...
...
```

Comment: Cannot edit just the line number, but it's https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/ops.py#L791 now.

Comment: @m-dz - I think this should be changed each version of pandas ;) thanks.

Comment: Couldn't agree more, there should be a keyword linking possible in GitHub!

Comment: I can't find it :(

Comment: I'm getting broken github links.

Comment: @O.rka - link was changed for master version.

Comment: Thank you!  This is really useful to have.  It's a little more complicated than I thought to apply for my situation but this is exactly what I was looking for.